# Cmd loop for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I would like to make this command loop for 30 seconds then say done:

```
@Echo off
pause
Title Matrix
Color 0A
:top
Echo %Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%­%Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%­%Random%%Random%%
(not loop the pause, just the %random%)
```

Comment: [Could you try to search first?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5970897/1418463)

Comment: Fixed your formatting, please double check that your *code* looks correct.

Comment: @Nikolay: This question asks how to loop until a certain amount of time has elapsed, and then exit. The question you referenced does not address that facet.

Comment: by "loop for 30 seconds" you mean sleep for 30 seconds after running the commands, or running commands 30 times ?

Comment: @Scott, you're right, but my point was to demonstrate that search can help. I found the link which I provided within 5 seconds after I saw the question. I believe that by spending 5-10 minutes one can find exact solution on one or another web site, since the question appears to be not super rare.

Answer (score 0):

This may just work

```
@echo off

set looptime=30
set /a "T1=(%time:~6,2% + %looptime% ) %% 60"

:loop
  Echo %Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%­%Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%%Random%­%Random%%Random%%
  set T2=%time:~6,2%
  if not %T1% == %T2% goto loop

:: continue with whatever
```

Comment: This, technically, does answer the question as asked -- but the question, as asked, implies a broader question. If the body of the loop (an `echo` statement, in the example) takes more than a second (or, for that matter, if your task gets pre-empted for more than a second), your solution might get consecutive values for `T2` that are non-consecutive integers, and so might skip over the value of `T1`. Also, if the requested duration is more than 60 seconds, your solution will run for only `looptime % 60` seconds.

Comment: @Scott you're right but this was not intended as a general all loop solution, just a particular solution to a very narrow and particular situation.